# What's the best way to implement JWT authentication with mixed client types?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

We currently use *Djoser* (with *simplejwt*), which has served us well. The only OAuth clients we had so far have been frontend apps.

However, we now have to add access for some external services. There is no appetite to have separate gatekeeper proxy. But we would like the option to set longer token life, etc for this client and *djoser/simplejwt* doesn't seem the best solution anymore.

DRF website has a [long list](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages) of third party libraries, which is great to have the choice, but makes the choice harder. Which of these packages, or another one that's not listed there, is a fairly easy replacement for *Djoser*? Ideally, it would be something which doesn't require us to write new views, etc for everything.